# Laravel 4 wkHtmlToPdf routes, POST and GET issue

Tags: post, laravel, laravel-routing

right,
I have installed the service provider for wkhtmltopdf (https://github.com/ignited/laravel-pdf)
and when I add

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    $pdf = PDF::make();
    $pdf->addPage('<html><head></head><body><b>Hello World</b></body></html>');
    $pdf->send();
});
```

in my routes.php it generates a pdf file.

What I am trying to do is to POST a whole div to my controller and then generate a PDF from that.

**My form:**

```
<form id="convert" action="{{{ URL::to('') }}}/pdf" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="body" id="body">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pdf" value="Done? Convert to PDF!">
</form>
```

**the jQuery:**

```
$('form#convert').submit(function(){
                  $("input#body").val($("#preview").html());
              });
```

**routes.php:**

```
Route::post('pdf', 'PdfController@index');
```

**and finally my controller (PdfController):**

```
<?php

class PdfController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $data = Input::get('body');


                $pdf = PDF::make();
            $pdf->addPage($data);
            $pdf->send('test.pdf');
            if(!$pdf->send())
        return $pdf->getError();
    }



}
```

Somehow I think it;s a basic POST vs GET thing, or I'm not doing things right.
Right now I get the error `Could not run command '/var/www/docassembly/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64'`

but if I replace my variable inside my controller by straight html I get the same error.

If I use GET in the form and the route and pass straight html as a parameter, the error is different:

```
Could not run command '/var/www/docassembly/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64' test /tmp/tmp_WkHtmlToPdf_Hq98EZ: Loading pages (1/6) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10% [============================================================] 100% Error: Failed loading page http://test (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
```

So having it in the controller is also an issue.
 Any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is quite simple, just needed to start the input with

`<html><head></head><body>` and end with `</body></html>`

As my input for whtml2pdf was the content of a div, I just had to insert those html tags into the value of the input being sent to the controller and voila.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation of the package](https://github.com/ignited/laravel-pdf) you have provided, it says that you need to include the binaries in your `composer.json` file to make it work:

---

*Note (you must also include wkhtmltopdf binaries)
32-bit systems*

```
{
    "require": {
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "*"
    }
}
```

*64-bit systems*

```
{
    "require": {
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "*"
    }
}
```

*You can include both of these if you need.*

---

Sounds like Laravel is trying to execute the 64bit binary and can't find it. Make sure that:

- You have it placed in the right folder.
- It has execution permission set with `chmod`.

Comment: The binaries are included and L can find them when my code is in routes.php but not inside my controller like I mentioned in my original post. I also manually navigated to the binaries to double-check.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually running your controller action? In your second error, seems like it's trying to load `Error: Failed loading page http://test`. Try using `URL::action('PdfController@index')` in the form `action` parameter.